# После установки питона возникла ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x, dll

После установки питона на винду 10 x64, при входе в саблайм выскочила ошибка missing python33.dll. В интернете никакой инфы нет. Как исправить данную ошибку и почему она возникла?

Answer (score 0):

не спец, но по моему либо переустановить питон.
 либо попробовать переустановить сублайм.
либо кинуть туда эти файлы
https://yadi.sk/d/LoalTGh2phGuAA
https://yadi.sk/d/o4OYOYbsw5twQQ